# Browser support for a specific code of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to detect if a browser supports `innerHeight`...

Is there any tag to check browser support for a specific code of JavaScript like that of `@supports` in CSS?

Answer (score 2):

InnerHeight has a 95.22% all-time browser support rating. Pretty sure you're safe using it. :)

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_window_innerheight

Answer (score 0):

You can use what you're trying to use in an "if" statement

```
if(window.innerHeight) 
    console.log("window.innerHeight supported"); 
else 
    console.log("window.innerHeight not supported");
div=document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
if(div.innerHeight) 
    console.log("div.innerHeight supported"); 
else 
    console.log("div.innerHeight not supported");
```

Comment: They want to check the support of a Window Interface's property, not of a CSS feature.

Comment: OH... i've misunderstood the question... Will modify it